# My Manndlebrot set is having weird artifacts

Tags: c

My code:

```
int main()
{
  int width = 720;
  int height = 720;
  int dpi = 200;
  rgb *pixels = malloc (sizeof (rgb) * width * height);

  double rstart = -2;
  double rend = 1;
  double imstart = -1;
  double imend = 1;

  double itr = 0;
  double r, img;
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
      {
        r = rstart + ((double) (x) / (double) (width)) * (rend - rstart);

        img = imstart + (((double) (y) / (double) (height))) * (imend - imstart);

        //printf("Number : %lf + %lfi Iterations : %d \n" , r , img ,mandlebrot(r , img)) ;

        itr = mandlebrot (r, img);

        itr = itr / (double) (MAX_ITR);
        pixels[x + y * width].r = (int) (9 * (1 - itr) * itr * itr * itr * 255);
        pixels[x + y * width].g = (int) (15 * (1 - itr) * itr * itr * 255);
        pixels[x + y * width].b = (int) (8.5 * (1 - itr) * itr * 255);
      }

  bitmap ("name.bmp", dpi, width, height, pixels);    
  return 0;
}
```

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBN1c.png)

```
int mandlebrot(double r, double img)
{
  double zr = 0, zi = 0;    // Initial Estimate for mandlebrot is zero
  double tmpr = 0, tmpi = 0;    // For better performance no use of imaginary nums
  int itr = 0;
  while (zr * zr - zi * zi <= 4 && itr < MAX_ITR)    
    {
      zr = zr * zr - zi * zi + r;
      zi = 2 * zi * zr + img;
      itr++;
    }
  return itr;        
}
```

I have tried everything but the artifacts are not going away. It also takes quite some time to generate large images. The colors also show banding even with quartic formula and changing the coordinates also doesn't show the details that were supposed to be there.

Comment: Are we supposed to derive your code from this picture? What is the question?

Comment: sorry stackoverflow was not accepting my code

Comment: should i also post the function that creates the final bitmap

Comment: `bitmap` - probably, no; `mandlebrot` - yes.

Comment: hopefully that helps

Comment: Why do you tag two different programming languages? Which one are you actually using?

Comment: What "weird artifacts" are you referring to?

Comment: _"I have tried everything"_ This statement doesn't tell us anything. Actually enumerate what you've done so far and why

Comment: i previously used the complex number support provided by c and still had artifacts . I have tried only black and white coloring which produced same images

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 my bad i am new to stackoverflow

Comment: I don't think newness on Stack Overflow is particularly relevant; pretend you're talking to a friend and ask yourself what information you would need to provide for them to help you. You've probably been doing that for years...

Comment: You've still got two language tags on the question

Comment: Fixed , Thanks guys for helping me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in here:

```
while (zr * zr - zi * zi <= 4 && itr < MAX_ITR)    
{
  zr = zr * zr - zi * zi + r;  //  This line changes Zr.
  zi = 2 * zi * zr + img;      // This line is supposed to use the OLD value of Zr, not the updated value from the line above
  itr++;
  return itr;
}
```

I also think you do not want to return `itr` until the loop is done.
Instead, you are returning `itr` from inside the loop!

To make it work try:

```
while (zr * zr - zi * zi <= 4 && itr < MAX_ITR)    
{
  double zr_old = zr;
  zr = zr * zr - zi * zi + r;  // Update Zr
  zi = 2 * zi * zr_old + img;  // Use the prior version of Zr, before the update.
  itr++;
}
return itr;  // Wait until the loop has exited normally.
```

Comment: thanks a lot , i am sorry for posting here because of a stupid mistake